# what does none in "tun0@none" stand for?

Tags: networking, ip, network-interface

In the output of `ip a` I just got the lines:

```
4: tun0@NONE: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
```

What does the NONE in there stand for?

Comment: I think it's because it doesn't have an IP address assigned to it yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the output format documentation](http://linux-ip.net/gl/ip-cref/ip-cref-node17.html),

> The interface name may have another name or `NONE` appended after the `@` sign. 
> This means that this device is bound to some other device,
> i.e. packets send [sic] through it are encapsulated
> and sent via the “master” device. 
> **If the name is `NONE`, the master is unknown.**

<sup>[Emphasis added.]</sup>

So your `tun0` interface is part of a **tun**nel bound to another networking device. The fact that `ip` does not know which one does not mean that the tunnel will not work.

Comment: The link is now http://linux-ip.net/gl/ip-cref/ip-cref-node17.html